# Dynamic Take in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: sql-server, linq, dynamic, data-retrieval

Let say I have the following tables:

```
Category: ID, Name, Limit
News: ID, Title
Relation: CID, NID
```

I want to select top 'x' news from News table with CID, CName and that 'x' depends on Category.Limit. For e.g

```
Category

ID        Name         Limit
1         A            2
2         B            3

News

ID        Title
1         News 1
2         News 2
3         News 3
4         News 4

Relation

CID       NID
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         4
2         3
2         2
2         1
```

Then we will have the result:

```
CID          CName        NID          NTitle

1            A            1            News 1
1            A            2            News 2
2            B            4            News 4
2            B            3            News 3
2            B            2            News 2
```

Is it possible to achieve the result with only 1 linq query? If not then a store procedure?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for each category, you want to have the first `x` news, where `x` is the limit of that category.

```
var result = context.Categories
                    .SelectMany(c => c.News
                                      .Take(c.Limit)
                                      .Select(n => new
                                                   {
                                                       CID = c.CID, 
                                                       CName = c.CName,
                                                       NID = n.NID,
                                                       NTitle = n.NTitle
                                                   }));
```

This answer assumes that the `Category` entity contains a navigation property `News` that contains all news that belong to a category.

Comment: Thanks for your ans but there is not a navigation property in `Category`. The relation between `Category` and `News` is stored in `Relation` table

Comment: I using EF and I use a table (Relation) to store the relationship between tables.

Comment: But in your entities there shouldn't be an entity named Relation. Normally, pure mapping tables are implemented as navigation properties in EF, i.e. your News entity should have a property that contains a list of Categories and vice versa. Please check this.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that so I remove all the constrains. There are no FK

Comment: @ByulTaeng: And why would you do that?! The navigation property are a help for you, not something you need to prevent.

Comment: As I said, there is only 1 table (Relation) to store all the realtionships (many-many), in order to limit the number of bridge table